# in array the image extension get variables

Tags: php

This code:

```
$extensions = array('.jpg', '.JPG', '.png' ,'.PNG' ,'.jpeg' ,'.JPEG');
$extension = explode(".", $extensions);
$image = $somepicture."*.".$extension."");
```

How to display only those uploaded images that have extensions from the array?

Comment: $extension variable is array. You have to access last index of it to get your extension (for example for "image.png" you'll have to access $extension[1])

Comment: that's some weird piece of code

Comment: possible duplicate of [php array image extensions in variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319256/php-array-image-extensions-in-variables)

Comment: Don't repost your exact questions, especially since this question is even more unclear than the first. Your 3rd line has a trailing `)` because it was a call to `glob()`.

Comment: sorry over-duplicate, but another not write back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have array of file names:

```
$files = array('file1.jpg', 'file2.PNG', 'file3.txt');
```

You might want to filter images only like this:

```
$extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
$images = array_filter($files, function($file) use ($extensions) {
     $pos = strrpos($file, '.');
     $extension = strtolower(substr($file, $pos + 1));
     return in_array($extension, $extensions);
});
```

(According to posts on php.net, `pathinfo` is a bit slower than raw `substr` operations.)

---

Testing:

```
print_r($images);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => file1.jpg
    [1] => file2.PNG
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple way you can do it by below way:

```
<?php
   $extensions = array('.jpg', '.JPG', '.png' ,'.PNG' ,'.jpeg' ,'.JPEG');
   $extension = pathinfo('$file_name');
   in_array($extension,$extensions);
   {
         $image = $somepicture."*.".$extension."");
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Language PHP. Example (Filename Extension):

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
print $imageFileType;
```

Result print PNG or other ur image extension. Before make ur form post. Example

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"></form>
```